# Minor bug when search includes "C++" it returns no results

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

To Repro:

1. Do a search with `C++` included, but no results [returned](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+someunknownterm)

Result:

- The first suggestion indicates that
  the search term is "C
  someunknownterm" while the rest still include C++
- The link in the first suggestion goes to the wrong search (Includes "C" instead of "C++")

Expected Result:

- "C++" should be included in the text and link in the first suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is sort of wrong, as c++ should be used as a tag. wontfix because we will be auto-converting any search terms that are high-count tags, into tags.

So if you enter

> c++ someunknownterm

we will convert it for you to

> [c++] someunknownterm

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware of the search syntax for that.