# Advanced Super Ninja Search bug? Valid Search does not return results

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, search

I was searching for certain answers within [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books), viz. Python books in the list of freely available programming books.
Following are various search queries and associated search results:

[image: stackoverflow search bug]

**Problem Statement:**

Cannot Search for "tag level words" within a question *(which does not have the specific tag*) for answers (*which cannot have tags*) viz *python*, even while using quotes or "+" to avoid auto detection as tag. 
But when another word is combined with the search query eg.*inquestion:194812 "python" dive*, you get results. This means that though the "engine" can search for the words *python* and *dive* within the question, it will not search for the word *python*, even if you use quotes to avoid tag detection.

A [similar problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71419/search-is-not-showing-full-correct-results) used to exist(?) before for plain searches (without the *inquestion* or any other tags), but currently one can search for "python" and get results which do not have python as a tag but has python in the question/answer body.
Screenshot for example using the "tag level word" *comet* in quotes to search for questions with *comet* in the body.
[image: quoted comet search]

**Is this a bug: Maybe.** Because I can avoid auto detection of tag level words by using quotes while searching, but if I use a *Advanced Super Ninja Search Option* like *inquestion* in conjunction, I fail to get results.

I am unsure if this is a bug, so I have included the feature request tag, it would be great to avoid auto tag detection and search for tag level words within a question.

<sub>(I have looked in all the other tabs too(relevance, votes, active etc.) )</sub>

Similar Questions:

[A similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9459/minor-bug-when-search-including-c-returns-no-results) was asked before

[Do not filter search results by tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10520/do-not-filter-search-results-by-tag)

[Bug: excluding tag from search does not work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73287/bug-excluding-tag-from-search-does-not-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We recently [changed the search engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out), which enables things like this to work better; searching for: **inquestion:194812 +python**  [now gets you the 22 results you are likely after](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=inquestion%3A194812+%2Bpython).

Remember to use **+python** here to prevent it from searching strictly on [the tag [python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).